# Adding content to element with custom scrollbar via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar, jscrollpane

Let's take the following div for example. The div is this small because I intend to add a scrollbar to it.

```
<div id='main' style='height:300px; overflow-y: auto;'>
   <!-- Content that is long enough to require a scrollbar... -->
</div>
```

Let's say I initialize a custom scrollbar on this div (malihu or jscrollpane) for example, with the following command:

```
jQuery("#main").jScrollPane(); // for jscrollpane
jQuery("#main").mCustomScrollbar(); // for malihu
```

This works just fine for the moment being, but when I add data to the div dynamically, it doesn't appear in the div, and the scrollbar is not adjusted:

```
jQuery("#main").append("Add this data to the div...");
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the solution. When creating any of the above scrollbars, they add two containers to the div which is attached to. You must append the content to these containers, and not to the basic div.

For example, to add content to jscrollpane scrollbar, you use:

```
 jQuery("#main").find(".jspPane").html("Data to be added...");
```

For malihu you would use:

```
jQuery("#main").find(".mCSB_container").html("Data to be added...");
```